# How would I organize the dicts into a list using this websites API?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

For a project I am using this websites API:

```
http://api.mapmyuser.com/userinfo.php?site=google.com&output=json
```

I am having difficulty separating the dicts into a list.  This is my code for the project so far:

```
import json

import urllib.request

import statistics

    def get_website_stats(website):
    url = 'http://api.mapmyuser.com/userinfo.php?site='+ website +'&output=json'
    lines = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()
    list_of_strings = []
    for obj in lines:
        list_of_strings.append(obj.decode('utf-8').strip('\n'))
    merged_string = ' '
    for string in list_of_strings:
        if string not in ('[', ']'):
            merged_string += string
    return json.loads(merged_string)

    symbol=input("What is the website name? (Do not include www)")
    stats = get_website_stats(symbol)
    print(stats['bro'])
```

If you read through the API it is obvious I am trying to print out the browser the user of the website is using but instead I get an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Could anyone help me organize the dicts into the list properly?  I think the problem is I am appending an entire line into each element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

in this case stats is a list.

```
print(stats[0]['bro'])
```

also here's a shorter version of your script:

```
import requests
url = 'http://api.mapmyuser.com/userinfo.php?site=www.google.com&output=json'
r = requests.get(url)
if r.ok:
    stats = r.json()
    if stats:
        print(stats[0]['bro']) # 1st entry
    for s in stats:
        print s['bro']
```

Comment: If you are using `requests` you should simplify the url with the parameter payload in `requests.get`.